# Compatibility Errors: Attribute 'uuid' is not allowed to appear in element 'jasperReport'

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Presently I'am working on *iReport 5.1.0*. I've created a report and integrated in *Openbravo* but am getting the following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'uuid' is not allowed to appear in element 'jasperReport'.
```

My previous version was *iReport 4.0.7*. I even deleted the previous version still am getting this error.

Can anyone help me how to upgrade my report to latest version

Comment: Try to open the old templates (*.jrxml* files) in *iReport 5.1.0* and recompile them. By the way, are you sure that your are using *JasperReports 5.1.0*? It seems to me, that you are using the old version of *JR* library.

Answer (score 0):

For Openbravo 2.50 you must use iReport 3.0.0 [click here](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ERP_2.50%3aDevelopers_Guide/How_to_develop_a_report)

For Openbravo 3.0 you must use iReport 4.0.1 [click here](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/How_to_create_a_Report)